# Firebase keeps showing old data container even after I've changed it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So this is the class that I'm trying to upload to Firebase:

```
public class Route {
    private String uniqueId;
    private long routeTime;
    private float distance;
    private List<Double> lat;
    private List<Double> lan;

    public Route(){
        uniqueId = "null";
        this.lat = null;
        this.lan = null;
    }

    public Route (String id ,long time, float distance, List<Double> lat, List<Double> lon){
        this.uniqueId=id;
        this.routeTime=time;
        this.distance=distance;
        this.lat=new ArrayList<Double>(lat) ;
        this.lan=new ArrayList<Double>(lon) ;
    }
```

Previously I didn't had the `lat` and `lon` lists and just had one list that contained Location type objects and that list name was points. I've changed it because the Location class doesn't have an empty constructor and Firebase had trouble retrieving the data.

The problem is that even after the change when I upload the data to firebase it "magically" transfer both lists into one Location list with the same name I gave it before the change.

This is the code where I upload to firebase:

```
        List<Double> lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> lon = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i=0; i<locationsList.size(); i++){ //locationsList is a list of Location
            lat.add(locationsList.get(i).getLatitude());
            lon.add(locationsList.get(i).getLongitude());
        }
        Route temp = new Route(routeUID,(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime())/1000,distance,lat,lon);
        currRoute.setValue(temp); //currRoute is a database reference
```

This is the declaration of locationList:

```
private  List<Location> locationsList;
```

And it's initialization:

```
locationsList = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

And this is the database after the last line:

[https://i.imgur.com/aVYDl1X.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNmo.png)

And this is the database path:

```
Routes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Routes");

currUserRoutes = Routes.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
currRoute = currUserRoutes.push();
routeUID = currRoute.getKey();
```

I have no idea how it transform both Double lists to one Location list and would appreciate the help.

Comment: show us you database path you are using in code

Comment: I've added it to the description

Comment: ok on firebase check all nodes under Routes, maybe you are checking wrong user and you had call setValue on another user id node

Comment: I've deleted the entire database after the change so there's only one node

Comment: locationsList.size() could you paste declaration and initialization of this List.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: clean your project and try to apply my updated suggestion

Comment: Thanks but I've applied the change and cleaned the build but the result is the same. I've added to the description the declaration and initialization of  locationsList

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! after some digging and experimenting I've found out that what I see in the data base is the return values of the functions and not the private values of the class [I habe a function that transform the 2 lists into one Location list].

Comment: its mean you didn't show us full code. glad to know that you succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Why you are initializing both ArrayList again? Try it, maybe this is the reason

Change this:

```
 public Route (String id ,long time, float distance, List<Double> lat, List<Double> lon){
            this.uniqueId=id;
            this.routeTime=time;
            this.distance=distance;
            this.lat=new ArrayList<Double>(lat) ;
            this.lan=new ArrayList<Double>(lon) ;
        }
```

To This:

```
public Route (String id ,long time, float distance, List<Double> lat,List<Double> lon){
                this.uniqueId=id;
                this.routeTime=time;
                this.distance=distance;
                this.lat=lat;
                this.lan=lon;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks but I've applied the change and cleaned the build but the result is the same. Firebase still saves the points list somehow instead of the 2 lat and lon lists.